# Publishing shapefile in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I started to use GeoServer, I uploaded shapefile and I want to publish it but I don't want to show all of the "Feature Type Details". For example, I want to publish only geometry. I know it's possible with SQL Views, but what about simple shapefile?

Comment: Read this http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html.

Comment: @user30184 does that mean there is no options in the GUI to limit the columns published in a service - only to edit the back-end files?

Comment: It means just that.